# In small network, how to provide ipv6 addresses in existing ipv4 subnet?

Tags: ipv6, ipv4

I have an ip4 192.168.0.0 subnet, with a few dozen hosts, and 6 or so servers with static IPs. I use bind 9 (On Centos 7) internally to service ip4 DNS requests. For years, I've disabled ip6, because I did not need it, and because there is no ip6 infrastructure, it would not work anyway. 
But now I have some applications where ip6 would be useful. I know basically nothing about ip6, but I need to provide ip6 addresses for at least my servers and provide name resolution.

I can install dhcp6, but I have already seen a client fail to start because it could not resolve a hostname to an ip6 address. I imagine I could create an ip6 zone in my bind 9 server, but I expect that I can't just choose any ip6 addresses I want.

What is the best way for my modest needs?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an IPv6 delegated prefix from your ISP (this is a /64 subnet for use internally, IPv6 does preferes not to use NAT, but instead use firewalls to filter traffic)?

Answer (score 0):

Generally...

1) setup an internal IPv6 scheme for your servers/computers to communicate over internally, you can use a [Local IPv6 generator](https://www.ultratools.com/tools/rangeGenerator) for this subnet.

2) Configure those servers with static IPs, something like

2001:db8::1 router
2001:db8::11 server 01
2001:db8::12 server 02

where 2001:db8 is the prefix you received randomly, these will be unique an internal only, if you have systems that never need an internet access but want IPv6 connectivity, you can use these IPs.

3) Request an IPv6 delegation from your ISP, these are you global addresses and how you connect to public servers via IPv6, they're "generally static" but no guarantees without a business contract with your ISP.  You can generally request as much as a /60 (16 /64 subnets, you'd use one for each vlan/network segment).  depending how your network is setup, you'd have a public IPv6 address on your router's WAN and the first IPv6 IP in your delegated /64 on your router's LAN, then DHCPv6 addresses from this to your devices to access the public internet with routable ipv6 addresses.